# Vue: navigation component is not displayed but seen in Vue extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I am using Vue after a long pause so sorry in advance for rather silly question.
I have a navigation component which is nested in layout component. The problem is that it is not visible on the page and in DevTools but I can see it in my Vue Chrome extension.

I feel like I am missing something really small but can't figure this out. Please help.

This my App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my Home page:

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <h1>Home page</h1>
  </Layout>
</template>

<script>
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.vue';


export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: { Layout },
};
</script>
```

This is Layout component:

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <Navigation />
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation.vue';


export default {
  name: 'Layout',
  components: { Navigation },
};
</script>
```

Everything is visible from Layout component except Navigation component. Here it is:

```
<template>
  <div class="navigation">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">
    Home
    </router-link>
    <nav>
      <!-- Nav routes -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navigation',
};
</script>
```

Comment: will you see `<div class="navigation">` in the rendered Dom (Chrome Console->Elements)?

Comment: No, I can't see this div. I only see `div class="main"` and then everything what is displayed in `<slot />`. Above `<slot />` in Elements I see only `<---->`. :(